# How to properly store the necessary info to register the user and other participants in the congress? (scenario 1 works but scenario 2 and 3 dont)

Tags: php, laravel, database-design

I have a registration form below for a user register in a congress. There are 4 different scenarios for the registration. So the registration form needs to handle this 4 different scenarios. But its not working, only the scenario 1 is working fine.

Do you know how to achieve this scenarios?

**Scenario 1: (the only scenario that is working fine)**

- there are two ticket types for the congress "ticket type 1" and "ticket type 2"
- the ticket type "tt1" has a custom question associate "Whats your phone?", the ticket type "tt2" dont have any custom question associated
- all participants is "1" which means that is necessary to collect info (name and surname) of each participant
- Diagram for this scenario:
  [image]

**Scenario 2:**

- there are two ticket types for the congress "tt1" and "tt2"
- the ticket types "tt1" and "tt2" dont have any custom question associated
- all participants is "1" which means that is necessary to collect info of each participant
- Diagram for this scenario:

[image]

**Scenario 3:**

- there are two ticket types for the congress "tt1" and "tt2"
- the ticket type "tt1" has a custom question associate "Whats your phone?", the ticket type "tt2" dont have any custom question associated
- all participants is "0" which means that is not necessary to collect info (name and surname) of each participant
- Diagram for this scenario: 
  [image]

**Scenario 4:**

- there are two ticket types for the congress "tt1" and "tt2"
- the ticket types "tt1" and "tt2" dont have any custom question associated
- all participants is "0" which means that is not necessary to collect info (name and surname) of each participant
- Diagram for this scenario: 
  [image]

The selected tickets from the previous page are available in the variable "`$selectedTypes`"

// registration form in the registration.blade.php page

```
      <form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    @if (!empty($allParticipants))
        @if($allParticipants == 1)
            <p>Please fill in all fields. Your tickets will be sent to
                p{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}.</p>

            @foreach($selectedTypes as $k => $selectedType)
                @foreach(range(1,$selectedType['quantity']) as $val)

                    <h6>Participant - {{$val}}  - {{$k}}</h6>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment_method" value="referencias">
                        <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                            <span class="mr-auto">Fill the following fields with the authenticated user information.</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                        <label for="participant_name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                        <label for="participant_surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ttypes[]" value="{{ $selectedType['id'] }}"/>
                    @foreach($selectedType['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                            <input type="text"
                                   @if($customQuestion->pivot->required == "1") required @endif
                                   class="form-control" name="participant_question[]">
                            <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]"
                                   value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
            @else
                <p>Its not necessary aditional info. Your tickets will be sent to {{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}.</p>

            @endif
        @endif

    <input type="submit" href="#step2"
           id="goToStep2Free" class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
</form>
```

// registration.blade.php complete method to register the user in the congress

```
public function StoreUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){
    $allParticipants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;
    $user = Auth::user();

    if($allParticipants){
        $rules = [
            'participant_name.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_surname.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'participant_question.*.required' => 'The participant is required'
        ];

        foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
            $rule = 'string|max:255'; // I think string should come before max
            //dd($value);
            // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
            if ($value) {
                $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
            }

            // add the individual rule for this array key to the $rules array
            $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;
        }

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        if($validator->passes()) {
            $registration = Registration::create([
                'congress_id' => $id,
                'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => 'C',
            ]);

            $participants = [];

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++)
                $participants[] = Participant::create([
                    'name' => $request->participant_name[$i],
                    'surname' => $request->participant_surname[$i],
                    'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                    'ticket_type_id' => $request->rtypes[$i]

                ]);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
                $answer = Answer::create([
                    'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$i],
                    'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
                    'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
                ]);
            }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);
    }


    else {

        $messages = [
            'participant_question.*.required' => 'The participant is required'
        ];


        foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
            $rule = 'string|max:255'; // I think string should come before max
            //dd($value);
            // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
            if ($value) {
                $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
            }

            // add the individual rule for this array key to the $rules array
            $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;
        }


        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);


        if ($validator->passes()) {

            $registration = Registration::create([
                'congress_id' => $id,
                'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
                'status' => 'C',

            ]);

            $participants = [];

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++)
                $participants[] = Participant::create([
                    'name' => '',
                    'surname' => '',
                    'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                    'ticket_type_id' => $request->rtypes[$i]

                ]);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
                $answer = Answer::create([
                    'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$i],
                    'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
                    'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
                ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'success'
        ], 200);

    }
}
```

Relevant models to the question:

```
class Congress extends Model
{
    // A conference has many ticket types
    public function ticketTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TicketType', 'congress_id');
    }

    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'congress_id');
    }
}

// RegistrationModel
class Registration extends Model
{
    // a registration has one user that do the registration (main_participant_id)
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }
}

class TicketType extends Model
{
    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }
}

class Question extends Model
{
    public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'ticket_type_questions')
            ->withPivot('required');
    }
}

class Answer extends Model
{
    public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Question');
    }
    public function participant(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Participant');
    }
}
```

Diagram that shows some issues with the code that I have for now that is the code  in the question:

[image]

Comment: JSON column for any optional info .

Comment: How does the `$request->participant_question_required` method generate its data? If it is an array in one instance, and `false` or `null` in another, don't you need to protect your `foreach` loop from trying to process non-existent data?

Comment: If in the registration from there are custom questions "                    @foreach($selectedType['questions'] as $customQuestion)" then in the storeUserInfo "$request->participant_question_required" exists otherwise is null which results in that invalid argument error. But with "if(isset($request->participant_question_required)) {" and then all code inside of this, like this, if the congress dont have any custom question associated then dont appears any error but no record are inserted in the registrations and participants table.

Comment: And in the registration form there is the "                            <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]". Is 0 or 1, 1 means required, false means not required.

Comment: And the "required" fields is a field of the pivot table ticket_type_questions that has this structure: id, ticket_type_id, question_id, required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two things

1.- The form doesn't send anything when $allParticipants == 0, maybe something more like:

```
    <form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    @if (!is_null($allParticipants) && is_int($allParticipants))
        @if($allParticipants == 1)   
            <p>Please fill in all fields. Your tickets will be sent to
                p{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}.</p>
        @else
            <p>Its not necessary aditional info. Your tickets will be sent to {{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}.</p>
        @endif

        @foreach($selectedTypes as $selectedType)
            @foreach(range(1,$selectedType['quantity']) as $test)
                <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$test}}</h6>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment_method" value="referencias">
                    <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center" for="exampleRadios1">
                        <span class="mr-auto">Fill the following fields with the authenticated user information.</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                @if($allParticipants == 1)
                    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                        <label for="participant_name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                        <label for="participant_surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
                    </div>
                   @foreach($selectedType['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                        <input type="text"
                                @if($customQuestion->pivot->required == "1") required @endif
                                class="form-control" name="participant_question[]">
                        <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]"
                                value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
                    </div>
                   @endforeach
                @else
                    <input type="hidden" value="foo" name="participant_name[]"/>
                    <input type="hidden" value="bar" name="participant_surname[]"/>
                @endif
                <input type="hidden" name="ttypes[]" value="{{ $selectedType['id'] }}"/>                
            @endforeach
            @if ($allParticipants == 0) 
              @foreach($selectedType['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                        <input type="text"
                                @if($customQuestion->pivot->required == "1") required @endif
                                class="form-control" name="participant_question[]">
                        <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]"
                                value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}" name="participant_question_id[]"/>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endif

    <input type="submit" href="#step2"
            id="goToStep2Free" class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
```

2.- Questions seems to depend on Ticket types and are optionals, the function should take it into account.

```
public function StoreUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){
    $allParticipants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;
    $user = Auth::user();

    $rules = [];
    $messages = [];

    if(isset($request->participant_question_required)) {
        $messages = [
            'participant_question.*.required' => 'The participant is required'
        ];

        foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
            $rule = 'string|max:255'; // I think string should come before max
            //dd($value);
            // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
            if ($value) {
                $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
            }

            // add the individual rule for this array key to the $rules array
            $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;
        }
    }

    if($allParticipants){
        $rules = [
            'participant_name.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
            'participant_surname.*' => 'required|max:255|string',
        ];
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

    if($validator->passes()) {
        $registration = Registration::create([
            'congress_id' => $id,
            'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
            'status' => 'C',
        ]);

        $participants = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++) {
            $name = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_name[$i] : '';
            $surname = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_surname[$i] : '';
            $participants[] = Participant::create([
                'name' => $name,
                'surname' => $surname,
                'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                'ticket_type_id' => $request->rtypes[$i]

            ]);
        }

        if (isset($request->participant_question))
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
                    $answer = Answer::create([
                        'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$i],
                        'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
                        'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
                    ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'success'
    ], 200);
}
```

Hope it works! 
Regards

Comment: Thanks, Im testing the first but when all_participants is "0" in the registration form dont appears any message, this dont appears "        <p>Its not necessary aditional info. Your tickets will be sent to {{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}.</p>". Do you kno why?

Comment: And also why is necessary "@else
                <input type="hidden" value="foo" name="participant_name[]"/>
                <input type="hidden" value="bar" name="participant_surname[]"/>
            @endif"?

Comment: empty($allParticipants) is true when $allParticipants == 0, so the first conditional should check `@if (! is_null($allParticipants) && is_int($allParticipants)) { ` 


I've added both hiddens because no textField would be send when $allParticipants == 0, so `count($request->participant_name)`  wouldn't work in the for cicle.

Comment: Thanks but still dont appears the  " <p>Its not necessary aditional info. Your tickets will be sent to {{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->email : old('email')}}.</p>".

Comment: <form method="post" id="step1form" action="">
                                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                                {{$allParticipants}} shows "0".

Comment: With "                                                @if (!is_null($allParticipants) && is_int($allParticipants))" it shows the message.

Comment: But if the user selected 2 tickets and that tickets have associated one or more custom questions, if all_participants is "0" it should only appear the custom question once, for the user that is doing the registration to answer. Because "all_participants" as "0" means that is only necessary to collect info from the user that is doing the registration. But is not working like that, if the user select 2 tickets that have custom questions associated it is appearing the custom question for each ticket (for each participant) instead of just appearing the custom question once for the auth user answr.

Comment: That form is getting ugly very fast, it should be generated in a more modular way, too many cases already.

Comment: Thanks, but still appears two input fields for the custom questions when the "all_participants" is 0, like: Participant - 1 - 1 Phone? Participant - 1 - 1 Phone? But it should appear only a input field for the user that is doing the registration (the authenticated user) to enter his phone.

Comment: Alt 1:
Maybe the Participant header should be outside the 2 @foreach, you can't get `$selectedType['questions']` outside of the first cicle. Problem is, you only get one header, no distinction between participants.

Alt 2:
It shouldn't cicle through ticket types.. as each one can have a different question even when allParticipants == 0.. or the same one as in your example.

Comment: Thanks, but if allParticipant is 0 then in the storeUserInfo() it can be used the id of the user that is doing the registration, the authenticated user with $user->id  like "                        'participant_id' => $user>id,
" no? But in the registration form dont know how it should be to work properly.

Comment: Do you know how the registration form can be organized to achieve the scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to store more than one ticket_type to a participant you will need to use a pivot table.  A pivot table is a table that only contains ids and relates data together in a many to many fashion.

e.g.

```
participants_ticket_type table
id      ticket_type_id   participant_id
1          1               2
2          2               2
```

Notice how participant 2 has ticket_types of 1 and 2?  This is a many to many relationship.

Laravel handles these relationships for you and you can find it in their docs.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Usually if you find yourself storing more than 1 id in a column a many to many relationship will solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks but I already have this relationships: 
`1 to many between Congress and Registration,
1 to many between Registration and Participant,
1 to many between TicketType and Participant`.

Comment: And the structure of these tables is like: `Congress: id, name, ...;
TicketType: id, congress_id, name,..;
Participants: id, registration_id, ticket_type_id, name, email;
Registration:id, status, congress_id`.

Comment: Is not possible to store in the participants table? Because having many to many between participant and ticket type dont seems correct because a participant is only associated with one ticket type, but a ticket type can have multiple participants.

Comment: It is possible however you will need to write some hacky code to get it working effectively. From my understanding you are saying "A Participant can have multiple ticket types". This would lead me to say that you require a pivot table between participant and ticket_type.

Comment: Thanks, but a participant cant have multiple ticket types a participant is only associated with one ticket type. For example, the user John can do a registration in a congress, a registration with 2 participants, him and other colluegue. And for this congress exist two ticket types "tt1" and "tt2 and John register him in the ticket type "tt1" and the other colluegue in the ticket type "tt2".

Comment: Its only  one registration with 2 participants, the participant John which is the main participant because did the registration is associated with the ticket type "tt1" the colleague is associated with the ticket type "tt2".

Comment: Ok, So to clarify are you saying "The person who registered with the congress can add people to the registration"? If so you are correct in what you wrote in your question where you just add in multiple people into the participants table with nulls. The only issue I have with that is if the same user wants to create another `registration` some of your data will be duplicated and you will need a pivot table similar to the answer to solve this.  I don't know your business case well enough to tell you if you need to worry about that :).

Comment: Ideally you would have the creator of the registration and participants in different tables. This will allow you to have the same user create multiple registrations. e.g. A registration contains `creator_id` and then a pivot table between `registration` and `participants`

Comment: Thanks, the creator of the registration and participants are in different tables. The creator of the registration is in the registration table with the column "main_participant_id" and the participants are in the participant table that has the columns (id, registration_id, ticket_type_id, name and surname).

Comment: A user can do a registrations in a conference and later do another registration in the same conference. But that should not be a issue because each registration has a different id. Also a user can, in the same congress registration, register many participants but each participanat will have a different id so that should also not be an issue no?

Comment: Im not understanding why is necessary a pivot table because the pivot table is only for many to many right? But Im not understanding which many to many is necessary in that context.

Comment: Its purely for reusability. I don't know your business case well enough to know what could happen e.g. what if you wanted a participant to be part of multiple registrations.  I think for now you are correct that your participants table has multiple rows for each registration.  Perhaps add in `is_creator_attending` column in the registration table so you don't have to put them into the participants table again.

Comment: Thanks, a user can do multiple registrations in the congress if he wants, so  can exist in the registrations table multiple "congress_id" and "main_participant_id" with the same ids, because the user that does the registration can do multiple registrations in the same congress, there is some issue there?

Comment: And the participants are not registered users in the system, are just names and surnames to associate to a ticket type. In the case that "all_participants" is "0" it should be only necessary to know which ticket types were registered and the main_participant_id.

Comment: I update the question with models to explain better the context.

Comment: The user that does the registration, that is the authenticated user, should only be stored in the registration table with the main_participant_id, it should not be stored anything in the participants table about the user that does the registration. But the user that does the registration can be a participant so in the participants table can apepar the name and surname of the authenticated user that did the registration if he is a participant of the congress.

Comment: Ok so you have a lot going on and its hard to actually pull out your 'question'.  I would recommend taking a big step back and finding out what your exact problems are and splitting them into more manageable chunks.

Answer (score -1):

First of all use `select * from TABLENAME` and then use the `COUNT` function either in the query Or use PHP `Count` function on the laravel blade file 
then execute your code..

on blade file

```
@if(count($records)>0){
   // Your Code

}
```